# How to change the format of new Date () and combine the result with a static time string

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to set new Date() together with a static time string like this "28.09.2019 22:00:00". The date should be the current, the time should always be 22:00:00. Therefore I used the code see below.

With the current code I get this result:
Sat Sep 28 2019 11:33:39 GMT+0200 (MESZ) 22:00:00

What I need is this (Current date, always same time):
28.09.2019 22:00:00

Another important thing ist, that the result should work with my formula in which I compare the result with other timestamps if they are higher or lower. The compared timestamps in my table are formatted as "Date/Time".

---

```
function TimeTrigger() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Tickerprüfung');  

  sheet.getRange("C2").setValue(new Date());
  sheet.getRange("C3").setValue(new Date() + " 22:00:00");

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function TimeTrigger() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Tickerprüfung');

  sheet.getRange('C2').setValue(new Date());
  var date = new Date();
  date.setHours(22);
  date.setMinutes(0);
  date.setSeconds(0);
  date.setMilliseconds(0);
  sheet.getRange('C3').setValue(date);
}
```

Comment: Great! This is it. Thank you very much.